# what happens if I'm asked to triage a question in a (human) language that I don't understand?

Tags: support, triage

I just got a request to triage a question. It's written in a foreign language that I don't understand. I don't see an option to indicate that I can't comprehend it. What to do next?
Please advise.

Comment: Questions on SO are required to be in English, so it's automatically Unsalvageable. Choose either "Needs details or clarity," or Off-Topic > custom reason.

Comment: And of course, if you aren't confident about reviewing a particular question, it's never wrong to hit Skip.

Comment: As @JohnMontgomery said "skip" is never wrong, but for non-English content there should be no need to use it - always vote to close. I bet in many cases it would be audit as such questions don't stay opened for long.

Comment: Only use custom reasons if you're **voting** to close (requires 3k rep). For flags, only use the "Needs details or clarity" reason because a custom flag reason is for moderator attention, which isn't necessary here.

Comment: Close-vote *flaggers* can choose from a generic "off-topic" close reason, @Davy, and that would be perfectly fine for non-English questions. Once you gain close-vote privileges, that generic "off-topic" close reason is replaced with a textbox where you can type an explanation as to *why* the question is off-topic.